# Using Makefile on Eclipse with MinGW

Tags: eclipse, makefile, mingw, stm32

I installed Eclipse with CDT for a STM32 project on Windows 10. I installed the ARM toolchain plugin and the GNU MCU Eclipse Windows Build Tools. Before that I already had MinGW and the GNU ARM toolchain.

I imported a Makefile project. I created a new target. When I double click on the new target, the right make command is executed however it looks like the compiler ( arm-none-eabi-gcc ) is not found.

```
13:37:35 **** Build of configuration Default for project Test2 ****
make all board=nucleo-l476rg app=cardio V=1 
Application: cardio
Board: nucleo-l476rg
[CC]     board.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c  -DCONFIG_LIB_BLUETOOTH -D __VFP_FP__ -D ARCH_NVIC_PRIORITY_BITS= -D CONFIG_IRQ_NVIC_RELOCATION  -D stm32l476xx -D __VFP_FP__ -D ARCH_NVIC_PRIORITY_BITS= -D CONFIG_IRQ_NVIC_RELOCATION  -D stm32l476xx -I drivers -I include -I drivers/bluetooth/stm32_bluenrg -I drivers/bluetooth/stm32_bluenrg/lib/include -D BLUENRG_CONFIG=BLUENRG_32_MHZ -I lib -O0 -g3 -ggdb -std=c99  -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -fms-extensions -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I include  -I arch/include -I arch/cortex-m4/stm32l4/include  -I arch/include -D CONFIG_ARCH_NVIC_PRIORITY_BITS=4 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -D stm32l4  -I boards/nucleo-l476rg  -MMD -MP -MT build/nucleo-l476rg/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.o -MF build/nucleo-l476rg/.dep/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.Td -o build/nucleo-l476rg/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.o boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.c
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'build/nucleo-l476rg/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.o' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -DCONFIG_LIB_BLUETOOTH -D __VFP_FP__ -D ARCH_NVIC_PRIORITY_BITS= -D CONFIG_IRQ_NVIC_RELOCATION -D stm32l476xx -D __VFP_FP__ -D ARCH_NVIC_PRIORITY_BITS= -D CONFIG_IRQ_NVIC_RELOCATION -D stm32l476xx -I drivers -I include -I drivers/bluetooth/stm32_bluenrg -I drivers/bluetooth/stm32_bluenrg/lib/include -D BLUENRG_CONFIG=BLUENRG_32_MHZ -I lib -O0 -g3 -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -fms-extensions -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -I include -I arch/include -I arch/cortex-m4/stm32l4/include -I arch/include -D CONFIG_ARCH_NVIC_PRIORITY_BITS=4 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -D stm32l4 -I boards/nucleo-l476rg -MMD -MP -MT build/nucleo-l476rg/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.o -MF build/nucleo-l476rg/.dep/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.Td -o build/nucleo-l476rg/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.o boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

make: *** [build/nucleo-l476rg/boards/nucleo-l476rg/board.o] Error 2

13:37:36 Build Finished (took 772ms)
```

Yet, I added the path of the compiler in Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment in the variable PATH.

I also tried to follow explanations from [this](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/plugins/install/) site but without success.

Thank you